# How can i launch my new android studio app with androidx as default

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello everytime i am launching a new android studio project i have to go to Refractor then Migrate to android X. Can this be able to be set automatically like when we are choosing the language for your project i.e java or kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Update your Android Studio to the latest version which is `3.4.2`.

**Step 2:** Create new Project.

**Step 3:** Select desired Activity

**Step 4:** In the next screen where it asks for project name and package information,
there is a option `Use androidx.* artifacts. This option is by default selected in the latest version. Check this to start your project with AndroidX by default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , your answer is a charm

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer if it solves your issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As of **Android Studio 3.3** and higher, when you are creating a new project you can see this option in project configuration panel as (`use androidX artifacts`), as you can see in below screenshot:

[image: use androidX artifacts]